# Any real-world HomeWSN deployments?

Tags: smart-home, mqtt

I searched for "MQTT Rules Engine", and came across the [HomeWSN](http://homewsn.com/) project.  It looks like it's almost trying to be a home automation system based on MQTT messaging, which could be very useful.  Has anyone deployed a real system based on this tool?

Comment: Good question, though I see the answer you are looking for is not just 'yes' or "no". So I think it would be better to tweak the question.

Comment: I haven't particularly used the tool but used rules engine in real case industrial application.

Comment: Project pages at HomeWSN.com do not contain much activity, latest entry in block since 2015 and in github there are little more activity since bugs are reported.

Based on the activity amounts it is not at least widely used.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as said by @bravokeyl "Good question, though I see the answer you are looking for is not just 'yes' or 'no'", so needs rephrase, to get sth meaningful out of this, or deletion.

Comment: @mico,  I'll rework the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been nearly 7 years since I asked this question, and a web search in 2024 still shows no relevant results.  I'm going to answer this as "no, there have been no real-world deployments of HomeWSN."